# Integrating over time the dot product of the volume integrals of current density and its time derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This question comes from electrodynamics, but I'm stuck at the math aspect.

Consider, in any volume $V \in \mathbb{R}^3$, two fields $\rho\left(\vec{r},t\right)$ and $\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right)$ related by the continuity equation $$-\frac{\partial \rho\left(\vec{r},t\right)} {\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right)$$
The variable $\vec{r}$ represents position, and $t$ is, of course, time. Now consider two time instants $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that for all $\vec{r} \in V$, $$\rho\left(\vec{r},t_1\right) = \rho\left(\vec{r},t_2\right),\qquad \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t_1\right) =\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t_2\right)$$
If we define two volume integrals like this:
$$
\vec{Y}\left(t\right)=
   \iiint_V 
      \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right) 
   \space dV\left(\vec{r}\right)
\qquad
\vec{Z}\left(t\right)=
   \iiint_V 
      \frac {\partial \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right)} {\partial t} 
   \space dV\left(\vec{r}\right)
$$
Can the following be proved?
$$
  \int_{t_1}^{t_2}
    \vec{Y}\left(t\right)
    \cdot
    \vec{Z}\left(t\right)
  \space dt
  = 0
$$
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your volume $V$ doesn't depends on time, you can exchange the order of
differentiation and integration (assuming all functions involved are regular enough).
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\vec{Y}(t) 
= \frac{d}{dt} \iiint_{V} \vec{J}(\vec{r},t)dV(\vec{r})
= \iiint_{V} \frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t}(\vec{r},t)dV(\vec{r}) = \vec{Z}(t)
$$
The integral you want can now be computed as follows:

$$\int_{t1}^{t2} \vec{Y}(t)\cdot\vec{Z}(t) dt = \int_{t1}^{t2} \vec{Y}(t)\cdot\frac{d\vec{Y}}{dt}(t) dt = \frac12 \int_{t1}^{t2} \frac{d}{dt}|\vec{Y}(t)|^2 dt = \frac12 \left[|\vec{Y}(t)|^2\right]_{t1}^{t2}$$

Since you assume $\vec{J}(t_1,\vec{r}) = \vec{J}(t_2,\vec{r})$ for all $\vec{r}$, you get
$\vec{Y}(t_1) = \vec{Y}(t_2)$ and hence: 
$$\int_{t1}^{t2} \vec{Y}(t)\cdot\vec{Z}(t) dt = \frac12 \left( |\vec{Y}(t_2)|^2 - |\vec{Y}(t_1)|^2 \right) = 0$$